# How to insert if not existing and update if existing (upsert)?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am currently having a confusion with:

```
var post = {ip: host, status: info};
var sql = con.query('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ipaddress SET ?', post, 
function(err, result){});
```

I have already set the IP address to primary key.

Comment: Which database is this? It appears to be Oracle, Postgres, or sqlite from a quick search.

Comment: I am using mysql

Comment: The operation you're referring to is called `UPSERT`. Knowing what to google is a key :P - Here is a nice article on multiple ways to do what you intend to do - https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

### Sequelize

Since you're using node.js, how about using [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/)?

> Sequelize is a promise-based ORM for Node.js v4 and up. It supports the dialects PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLite and MSSQL and features solid transaction support, relations, read replication and more.

It doesn't matter if you don't know SQL well because you can use its built-in functions. For example, if you want to perform an `upsert`:

```
ipaddress.upsert({
    ip: host,
    status: info,
});
```

### Pure MySQL

If you still want to use MySQL, use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to perform an upsert.

```
var sql = `INSERT INTO post (ip, status) VALUES (${host}, ${info}) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ip=${host}, status=${info}`;
```

But you need to take care some potential issues like SQL injection.

Comment: So what is safer to use sequelize? or pure mysql?