# MySQL Insert and update multiple rows in Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am using Express and  MYSQL.  This is my parameters

```
 var values = [
      [ 9, 1, 'input_4', 'Rj', 1 ],
      [ 9, 2, 'input_1', 'hk', 1 ],
      [ 9, 3, 'input_2', 'Vk', 1 ]
    ]
```

This is my Query

> INSERT INTO
> `form_meta`(`form_id`,`sequence`,`meta_key`,`meta_label`,`is_active`)
> VALUES ?
>
> **which is working fine.**

No i want if i pass

```
   var values = [
          [ 9, 1, 'input_4', 'Raj K', 1 ],
          [ 9, 2, 'input_1', 'Kumar', 1 ],
          [ 9, 3, 'input_2', 'Vinit Kumar', 1 ]
        ]
```

this needs to update not insert
I am using this query

> ```
>  var query = "INSERT INTO `form_meta`(`form_id`,`sequence`,`meta_key`,`meta_label`,`is_active`)
> ```
>
> VALUES ? ON Duplicate Key sequence= VALUES(sequence)";
>
> ```
>     connection.query(query,[values],cb);
> ```

it gives me error

> **Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax;**

Any Idea?

Comment: if  there is new row. i want to insert it as well.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51760879/how-to-insert-if-not-existing-and-update-if-existing-upsert

Answer (score 0):

It should be on duplicate key update sequence=values (sequence)